# Serialize the response from backend to store ember store

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

My response from backend is not in form which ember store. I am not able to serialize the response.

response.json

```
[{
    "pk": 127,
    "url": "http://example.com/api/galleries/127/",
    "gallery_name": "Faces",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/2656a05c-4ec7-3eea-8c5e-d8019454d443.jpg",
    "time": "1 month ago",
    "description": "Created by user",
    "is_following": true,
    "feedPhotos": [{
            "pk": 624,
            "url": "http://example.com/api/photos/624/",
            "profilePic": "https://example.cloud.net/userDPs/50906ce2-394d-39c8-9261-8cf78e3611c2.jpg",
            "userName": "Nabeela",
            "userKarma": 915,
            "caption": "Old woman spinning her 'chhos-khor' ...a rotation of which is equivalent to the recitation of a mantra.",
            "numComments": 0,
            "owner": "http://example.com/api/users/44/",
            "time": "1 month ago",
            "photo_url": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/9cbd6423-3bc5-36e0-b8b4-d725efb3249a.jpg",
            "comments_url": "http://example.com/api/photos/624/comments/",
            "numFives": 4,
            "fivers_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/1362/fivers/",
            "fivers_pk": 1362,
            "fullphoto_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/1362/photo/",
            "fullphoto_pk": 1362,
            "is_fived": true,
            "hiFiveKarma": 1,
            "owner_pk": 44,
            "userFirstName": "Nabeela",
            "is_bookmarked": false
        }, {
            "pk": 574,
            "url": "http://example.com/api/photos/574/",
            "profilePic": "https://example.cloud.net/userDPs/b6f69e4e-980d-3cc3-8b3e-3eb1a7f21350.jpg",
            "userName": "Rohini",
            "userKarma": 194,
            "caption": "Life @ Myanmar!",
            "numComments": 0,
            "owner": "http://example.com/api/users/45/",
            "time": "2 months ago",
            "photo_url": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/eeae72d5-d6af-391e-a218-b442c0c7e34e.jpg",
            "comments_url": "http://example.com/api/photos/574/comments/",
            "numFives": 2,
            "fivers_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/1303/fivers/",
            "fivers_pk": 1303,
            "fullphoto_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/1303/photo/",
            "fullphoto_pk": 1303,
            "is_fived": false,
            "hiFiveKarma": 0,
            "owner_pk": 45,
            "userFirstName": "Rohini",
            "is_bookmarked": false
        }
    ]
}, {
    "pk": 65,
    "url": "http://example.com/api/galleries/65/",
    "gallery_name": "Royal",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/d8a900af-1f1d-3977-8cc8-b8bb36e32be5.jpg",
    "time": "2 months ago",
    "description": "This is a gallery about Royal",
    "is_following": false,
    "feedPhotos": [{
        "pk": 347,
        "url": "http://example.com/api/photos/347/",
        "profilePic": "https://example.cloud.net/userDPs/50906ce2-394d-39c8-9261-8cf78e3611c2.jpg",
        "userName": "Nabeela",
        "userKarma": 915,
        "caption": "I cannot forget the name of this palace - Moti Mahal (translation: Pearl Palace). Indescribably beautiful, ainnit! at Mehrangarh fort, Jodhp",
        "numComments": 0,
        "owner": "http://example.com/api/users/44/",
        "time": "2 months ago",
        "photo_url": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/958ed406-708e-3f01-a2f4-9467cd709fdd.jpg",
        "comments_url": "http://example.com/api/photos/347/comments/",
        "numFives": 4,
        "fivers_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/759/fivers/",
        "fivers_pk": 759,
        "fullphoto_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/759/photo/",
        "fullphoto_pk": 759,
        "is_fived": false,
        "hiFiveKarma": 0,
        "owner_pk": 44,
        "userFirstName": "Nabeela",
        "is_bookmarked": false
    }, {
        "pk": 593,
        "url": "http://example.com/api/photos/593/",
        "profilePic": "https://example.cloud.net/userDPs/95ac6974-f7df-338c-ab84-99fa1df7514c.jpg",
        "userName": "Vikanshu",
        "userKarma": 932,
        "caption": "Marvelous architecture!! in Florence, Italy",
        "numComments": 0,
        "owner": "http://example.com/api/users/48/",
        "time": "1 month ago",
        "photo_url": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/7a86eb37-6c68-3d6c-b6cf-2e3b74d330dd.jpg",
        "comments_url": "http://example.com/api/photos/593/comments/",
        "numFives": 4,
        "fivers_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/1363/fivers/",
        "fivers_pk": 1363,
        "fullphoto_url": "http://example.com/api/photogalleries/1363/photo/",
        "fullphoto_pk": 1363,
        "is_fived": false,
        "hiFiveKarma": 0,
        "owner_pk": 48,
        "userFirstName": "Vikanshu",
        "is_bookmarked": false
    }]
}]
```

How do I serialize this using JSONPISerailizer or any other serializer in ember-cli so that it gets stored in ember store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/)
++++Top Level:
Root:
A JSON object must be root of every JSON API request response.
A document must contain at least one top-level members:
1. data: documents "primary data" 
2. errors: an array of error objects (id,status,code,title....)
3. meta: a meta object that contains non-standard meta-information (copyright,author...)

member data and errors must not co-exist together.
"data"{}

+++++Resource Objects
1. A resource object MUST contain atleast following top-level member
*id
*type

````
```
//structure-1
//for galleries
{
  "data": {
    "type": "galleries",
    "id": "1"
  }
}

//for photos
{
  "data": {
    "type": "photos",
    "id": "1"
  }
}
```
````

2. In addition, a resource object may contain any of these top-level members
   *attributes
   *relationship
   *links
   *meta

//added attributes first

````
```
//structure-2
//for galleries
{
  "data": {
    "type": "galleries",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "galleryName": "Faces"
      "thumbnailUrl:"https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/2656a05c-4ec7.jpg",
      "description": "Created by user",
    }
  }
}

//for photos
{
  "data": {
    "type": "photos",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes":{
       userName: "Nabeela",
       userKarma: 915
     }
  }
}
```
````

//Adding relationship
Relationship object must contain atleast one of the following
*links (containing atleast one of "self" or "related" resource link
*data
*meta

````
//link in relationship (minimum one required from link,data,meta).
//
```
//structure-3
//for galleries
{
  "data":[{  //Array(square bracket as adding relationship one more item to data
    "type": "galleries",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "galleryName": "Faces"
      "thumbnailUrl:"https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/2656a05c-4ec7.jpg",
      "description": "Created by user",
    },
    "relationships":{
       "links":{
      "self": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/9cbd6423.jpg //"photo_url" in your payload
    },
    }]
  }
}
```
````

//data in relationship

````
```
//structure-4
//for galleries
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "galleries",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "galleryName": "Faces"
      "thumbnailUrl:"https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/2656a05c-4ec7.jpg",
      "description": "Created by user",
    },
    "relationships":{ //This has all your photo stuff
       "links":{
      "self": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/9cbd6423.jpg //"photo_url" in your payload
    },
    "data": {       //picked it up from structure-1
          "type": "photos",
          "id": "77"
    }
    }]
  }
}
```
````

//Adding related resource "included"

```
//for galleries

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "galleries",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "galleryName": "Faces"
      "thumbnailUrl:"https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/2656a05c-4ec7.jpg",
      "description": "Created by user",
    },
    "relationships":{ //This has all your photo stuff
       "links":{
      "self": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/9cbd6423.jpg //"photo_url" in your payload
    },
    "data": {       //picked it up from structure-1
          "type": "photos",
          "id": "77"
    }
    }],
    "included":[{
        "type": "photos",
        "id": "77",
        "attributes":{
            userName: "Nabeela",
            userKarma: 915
        },
    {
        "type": "photos",
        "id": "78",
        "attributes":{
            userName: "Nabeela",
            userKarma: 915
        }
   }]

  }
}
```

## ```

For collections. I am not confident but try this

Now for collection of galleries.

//for galleries

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "galleries",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "galleryName": "Faces"
      "thumbnailUrl:"https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/2656a05c-4ec7.jpg",
      "description": "Created by user",
    },
    "relationships":{ //This has all your photo stuff
       "links":{
      "self": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/9cbd6423.jpg //"photo_url" in your payload
    },
    "data": {       //picked it up from structure-1
          "type": "photos",
          "id": "77"
    }
    },{
    "type": "galleries",
    "id": "2",
    "attributes": {
      "galleryName": "Faces"
      "thumbnailUrl:"https://example.cloud.net/galleryThumbs/2656a05c-4ec7.jpg",
      "description": "Created by user",
    },
    "relationships":{ //This has all your photo stuff
       "links":{
      "self": "https://example.cloud.net/photos/9cbd6423.jpg //"photo_url" in your payload
    },
    "data": {       //picked it up from structure-1
          "type": "photos",
          "id": "79"
    }
    }],
    "included":[{
        "type": "photos",
        "id": "77",
        "attributes":{
            userName: "Nabeela",
            userKarma: 915
        },{
        "type": "photos",
        "id": "78",
        "attributes":{
            userName: "Nabeela",
            userKarma: 915
        },{
        "type": "photos",
        "id": "79",
        "attributes":{
            userName: "Nabeela",
            userKarma: 915
        }
   }]

  }
}
```

============Implementation part =================================

JSONSerializer normalization process follows these steps

*normalizeResponse : entry method.
*normalizeCreateRecordResponse : a normalizeResponse for specific operation.
*normalizeSingleResponse|normalizeArrayResponse: 
- for methods like createRecord. we expect a single record back.
- for methods like findAll we expect multiple records back.

+normalize = 
normalizeArray iterates and calls normalize for each of it's records 
normalizeSingle call its once.

+extractID | extractAttributes | extractRelationships
= normalize delegates to these method to  turn record payload into jsonAPI format

Starting with normalizeResponse method. If you open and see normalizeResponse method

in json-serializer
link normalizeResponse: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.2.1/packages/ember-

data/lib/serializers/json-serializer.js#L192

you with find a switch case `switch(requestType)`. If requestType if 
"findRecord"  then "normalizeFindRecordResponse" is called
"queryRecord" then "normalizeQueryRecordResponse" is called
"findAll"     then "normalizeFindAllResponse" is called
...so on and so forth.
if you notice the parameter passed to all the methods are same as that of normalize

(...arguments) :)

**Lets start for findAll
i.e normalizeResponse -> normalizeFindAllResponse -> normalizeArrayResponse
as normalizeFindAllResponse method has only one line that call

normalizeArrayResponse.

[normalizeFindAllResponse](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.2.1/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json-serializer.js#L277)

normalizeResponse -> normalizeFindAllResponse -> normalizeArrayResponse ->

_normalizeResponse{ extractMeta,normalize }

extractMeta [extract meta information like pagination and stuff ]
if single: normalize []

example of normalize method in emberjs docs

````
```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function(typeClass, hash) {
    var fields = Ember.get(typeClass, 'fields');
    fields.forEach(function(field) {
      var payloadField = Ember.String.underscore(field);
      if (field === payloadField) { return; }

      hash[field] = hash[payloadField];
      delete hash[payloadField];
    });
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```
````

"normalizeArrayResponse calls `return this._normalizeResponse

(store,primaryModelClass,payload,id,requestType,false).
so isSingle is false for  _normalizeResponse method. so we will have to push all the

related records of included array
in our case the photos which is done by below snippet from "_normalizeRespose"

method.
 [_normalizeResponse](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.2.1/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json-serializer.js#L420)

````
```
else{
  documentHash.data = payload.map((item) => {
    let { data, included } = this.normalize(primaryModelClass,item);
    if(included){
      documentHash.included.push(...included);
    }
    return data;
  });

  return documentHash;
}
```
````

Things are still unclear in the context of our JSON reponse from server
but atleast we know the flow now.

Lets try to apply it for findAll ( as per the flow above).

1. run "ember g serializer application" //assuming you are using ember-cli and you

intend to make this serializer generic for  application.

**As of now I have no information how and when normalizeResponse is called.** :( 
I just scanned through and guess on recieving data from server the store calls

normalizeResponseHelpers which in turn calls normalizeResponse.

In any case "normalizeResponse" is going to send payload and other necessar

information to normalizeFindAllResponse(...arguments) which in turn will call

normalizeArrayResponse(...arguments) which in turn will call "_normalizeRespone".

Here is where we need to take action
for extraMeta and normalize.
+extraMeta 
I am not sure if there is any meta information in you json response.
in case there is you can refer to the example mentioned in docs

[extractMeta](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#method_extractMeta)

So I guess you can directly user the normalize method from example in your application ;).

**please try and check. Since i am learning ember myself I cannot guarantee it will work but it should. the lonngggg explation is my thought while i was learning the problem/solution**

````
//app/serializers/application.js

+normalize
```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function(typeClass, hash) {
    var fields = Ember.get(typeClass, 'fields');
    fields.forEach(function(field) {
      var payloadField = Ember.String.underscore(field);
      if (field === payloadField) { return; }

      hash[field] = hash[payloadField];
      delete hash[payloadField];
    });
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```
````

The primary key in the JSON from server is pk. You will have to mention that too

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#property_primaryKey
app/serializers/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'pk'
});
```

Comment: its work but store only the fisrt result of  reposnse .my model is this.  gallery_name:attr('string'),
     thumbnail_url:attr('string'),
     is_following:attr('boolean'),
     time:attr('string'),
     description:attr('string'),
     feedPhotos:attr()                                              and my route is this.store.findAll('feed'),

Comment: I see pk in feedPhotos and I assumed gallery hasMany feedPhotos. so feedPhotos should be feedPhotos : DS.hasMany('photos') //something like this.  I have update the answer for primaryKey please check

Comment: Please mark accepted if the answer works. you can use [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) to reproduce your problem so that more people will be able to help